Error connecting to Event Hubs from spring applications - reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented
I want to connect to event hub from Spring boot
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/using-event-hubs-in-spring-applications
Use Spring Cloud Azure Event Hubs Starter model
My spring version
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <spring-cloud-azure.version>5.11.0</spring-cloud-azure.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-eventhubs</artifactId>
</dependency>

application yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    azure:
      eventhubs:
        namespace: contosoehu40008.servicebus.windows.net
        event-hub-name: contosoehub100907
        processor:
          checkpoint-store:
            account-name: storageacc1999934
            container-name: data
          consumer-group: $Default

Configuartion class as mentioned in Azure documentation

EventHubProcessorClientConfiguration
EventHubClientApplication

Error:
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: com.azure.core.amqp.exception.AmqpException: errorContext[NAMESPACE: contosoehubns0099998.servicebus.windows.net.servicebus.windows.net. ERROR CONTEXT: N/A]
Caused by: com.azure.core.amqp.exception.AmqpException: errorContext[NAMESPACE: contosoehubns000008.servicebus.windows.net.servicebus.windows.net. ERROR CONTEXT: N/A]
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ExceptionUtil.toException(ExceptionUtil.java:90) ~[azure-core-amqp-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.ConnectionHandler.notifyErrorContext(ConnectionHandler.java:363) ~[azure-core-amqp-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.ConnectionHandler.onTransportError(ConnectionHandler.java:259) ~[azure-core-amqp-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.BaseHandler.handle(BaseHandler.java:191) ~[proton-j-0.33.8.jar:na]
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.EventImpl.dispatch(EventImpl.java:108) ~[proton-j-0.33.8.jar:na]
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.dispatch(ReactorImpl.java:324) ~[proton-j-0.33.8.jar:na]
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.process(ReactorImpl.java:291) ~[proton-j-0.33.8.jar:na]
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorExecutor.run(ReactorExecutor.java:91) ~[azure-core-amqp-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

Other configurations:
Added this security ,as I found this in some documentation. Not sure if this is required or not

To grant your account access to resources, in Azure Event Hubs, assign
the Azure Event Hubs Data Receiver and Azure Event Hubs Data Sender
role to the Microsoft Entra account you're currently using. Then, in
the Azure Storage account, assign the Storage Blob Data Contributor
role to the Microsoft Entra account you're currently using. For more
information about granting access roles, see Assign Azure roles using
the Azure portal and Authorize access to Event Hubs resources using
Microsoft Entra ID.

How can I resolve / troubleshoot the issues?

The example model 2  "Build the client programmatically" works a little , may be one cycle and then prints stack trace - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot subscribe. Processor is already terminated. , The program does not EXIT, but repeats the cycle. - Starting next iteration of load balancer. Microsoft put a disclaimer to not use this model 2, but at least it runs for a moment. I still need answer to my question original question.
